# Delete number from random array and return array with n random numbers?

Tags: arrays, ruby, random, shuffle

I want to make one method in Ruby which returns one random number from an array and made this:

```
@nr = 1..60

def ar_one
    ar = @nr.to_a.shuffle
    ar.pop
end
```

But I get the numbers more than one time and the array is never nil.
What's wrong with this?

And I need a method which give me n*random_numbers_from_array.
So if I say n=3 than than I want to have: [12, 1, 59] something like this and delete this 3 numbers at there index.
I tried this but I only get one random number at index n-1 nothing more.

```
def ar_all(n=3)
    arr = []
    @nr.each do |nr|
        arr.insert(n-1,ar_one)
        n += -1
    return arr
end
end
```

Would be great if someone can say which mistake I made in `arr_one` and how to get all n random numbers in `arr_all`.

Comment: Your title and first sentence are contradictory. The former needs to be corrected.You evidently want to return the deleted number, not the resulting array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you actually create a new array each time you run the `ar_one` method.

```
ar = @nr.to_a.shuffle # <= here you create a new array and shuffle it
ar.pop                # <= here you pop and return the first element of that new array
```

Your second example fails, because you return from that method at the end of the first iteration of the `each` block, right after collection just one element:

```
@nr.each do |nr|
  arr.insert(n-1,ar_one)
  n += -1
  return arr          #<= here you return from that method without checking `n`
end
```

---

I would do something like this:

```
class Sampler
  def initialize(number = 60)
    @array = (1..number).to_a.shuffle
  end

  def one
    @array.pop
  end

  def many(number)
    @array.pop(number)
  end
end

sampler = Sampler.new(4)
sampler.one
#=> 2
sampler.many(3)
#=> [3, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a simple and easy way:

```
@array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

def random_collector
  number = @array.sample
  index = @array.index(number)
  @array.delete_at(index)
  number    
end
```

Comment: Thanks this helps me to get my 6 random numbers in my second code but the array = array-[number] don't delete the numbers from the array in my code:

num = 1..7

def ar_one
   a = num.to_a
   nr = a.sample
   num = num.to_a-[nr]
   nr
end


def ar_all(n=6)
 a = num.to_a
 nr = a.sample(n)
 num = num.to_a-[nr]
 nr
end

Comment: What if `@array = [1,1,1,1,2]`? If `1` is returned when the method is called, `@array = [2]` when it is called next. I suggest simply `@array.delete_at(rand(@array.size)`.

Comment: How could `index` be `nil`? The last line is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

```
def random_collector
  @array.delete_at(rand(@array.size))
end
```

If `@array` is not to be modified, operate on a copy.